# The page isn't redirecting properly when i try to call drupal_get_form

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-fapi, drupal-forms

Why Drupal 7 cannot redirect properly (I've logged in)?

When I'm trying to call drupal_get_form('user_login') from my module in hook_preprocess_page(), the browser throw that message.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please read the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  You will need to provide more details if you want someone to answer.  In this case, you didn't specify what message you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Drupa_get_form() function is not for redirecting. It is for getting a form. In your case, you are calling the login form. To redirect, use the drupal_goto() function here is a link on the drupal api
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7

Answer (score 0):

Well, `drupal_get_form('user_login')` causes the issue. So instead of `drupal_get_form('user_login')` use `drupal_get_form('user_login_block')` and it will work.